# Laravel Guzzle Basic Auth returns empty on success

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Here's my code below.
When I make a successful authorization, $this->token gets empty value. 
When I try this function with PHP Curl, It works well with no problem.

What could be the problem?

By the way, If I try wrong password or username, It gives error.

```
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $response = $client->get($this->url . "/auth/getToken", [
      'auth' => [
        'myuser',
        'mypassword'
      ]
  ]); 
$this->token = $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code example, `$this->token` will be an instance of `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` whose implementation will contain arrays, integers and a stream resource.  Depending on how it is utilized in subsequent code it may appear to be an "empty value" based on how PHP itself tries to cast it.

If we assume that the entire contents of the response body, is the desired authentication code (not well formatted json), we can modify the example to be:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get($this->url . "/auth/getToken", [
    'auth' => [
    'myuser',
    'mypassword'
  ]
]); 
$this->token = $response->getBody()->__toString();
// the __toString() is written to make PHP's casting explicit
```

or:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$this->token = $client->get($this->url . "/auth/getToken", [
    'auth' => [
    'myuser',
    'mypassword'
  ]
])
    ->getBody()
    ->__toString();
// the __toString() is written to make PHP's casting explicit
```